# Pass data from one project to another

Tags: c#

I have Project1 as main solution under which I have Project2 and Project3.

Project2 is referenced in Project3 but now I need to pass data from Project3 to Project2

When I try to reference Project3 in Project2 I get error saying

> Cyclic reference not allowed

How can I pass data from Project3 to Project2?

The data I need to pass is

```
var events = WasteFinder.BL.Managers.EventManager.GetItemsGraph(dt)
```

Comment: You cannot reference P1=>P2 and P2=>P1 at the same time. Reconsider your architecture

Comment: i know that i can't do this so what can be the solution... i cant remove P2 as reference in P3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a **circular reference**. Analyze what components and relations you need and remove this dependency. You probably need to exctract logic into **a separate independent project**, that is referenced from your projects.

You probably need to read up about design patterns and architecture. Try drawing your system on a board, it will help you to decide how to structure it.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options to try it out:

**Option 1#**

Create another project called `Common Project` and move the common logic between Project 2 & Project 3 in it. Then refer this project in other two.

```
Project 2 ->  
     |          Common Project
Project 3 ->
```

**Option 2#**

Though you already have `Project 1`, so instead of creating a `Common Project` you can use `Project 1` instead.

```
Project 2 ->  
     |          Project 1
Project 3 ->
```

Answer (score 0):

If both Projects 2 & 3 have access to Project1, why don't you simply use something in Project1 to pass the message?

Answer (score 0):

If the data which you require is must and many things needs to be shared then you can have one more project which will be referenced to both projects i.e. p2 and p3. This project can be termed as common project.

I hope it will help you.. :)